# Configure RestSharp XML serializer

Tags: xml-serialization, restsharp

I have a .Net Core 3.1 console app to communicate with my WebApi app. Is there a way to configure the XML serializer that RestSharp uses for its RestRequest.AddBody() method? I need to add some XmlWriterSettings to it.

Comment: You can look at the default XML serializer code, and you'll see that it uses the `Serialize` function of the `XmlSerializer`, which doesn't have any overloads to specify writer settings. It's not hard, though, to create a custom serializer.

Comment: I think it's easy to change the default serializer also, so if you submit a PR, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I've decided to alter my classes, to be fully serializable